# Replacing "\xe9" character from a unicode string in Python 3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, sublimetext

Using SublimeText 2.0.2 with Python 3.4.2, I get a webpage with urllib :

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
pagehtml = response.read()
```

Print => `qualit\xe9">\r\n\t\t<META HTTP`

I get a "\xe9" character within the unicode string!

The header of the pagehtml tell me it's encoded in ISO-8859-1
(`Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1`). But if I decode it with ISO-8859-1 then encode it in utf-8, it only get worse...

```
resultat = pagehtml.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Print => `qualit\xc3\xa9">\r\n\t\t<META HTTP`

How can I replace all the "\xe9"... characters by their corresponding letters ("é"...) ?

### Edit 1

[image: Erreur UTF]

I'm getting an `UnicodeEncodeError` (that's why I was encoding in 'utf-8') !

**I should mention I'm running my code within SublimeText 2.0.2**. It's seems to be my problem.

### Edit 2

It is working fine in IDLE (Python 3.4.2) and in OSX terminal (Python 2.5) but don't work in SublimeText 2.0.2 (with Python 3.4.2)... => That seems to be a **problem with SublimeText console** (output window) and not with my code.

I'm gonna look at `PYTHONIOENCODING env` as suggested by J.F. Sebastian
It's seems I should be able to setting it in the `sublime-build file`.

### Edit 3 - Solution

I just added `"env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "UTF-8"}` in the `sublime-build file`.

Done. Thanks everyone ;-)

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: unrelated: `response.headers.get_content_charset()` returns the character encoding specified in Content-Type HTTP header.

Comment: what version of Sublime Text are you using?

Comment: @MattDMo. SublimeText 2.0.2. I got the solution. Thanks (See edit in post)

Comment: what is the location of the sublime build file?

Comment: @partizanos. Use `Tool > Build System`, then either edit the one you need or start a new one. When saving, Sublime Text should automaticaly show you the rigth folder to save the file. On my mac, it's in `User / XX / Library / Application support / Sublime Tewt 2 / Packages / User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting an UnicodeEncodeError (that's why I was encoding in 'utf-8') ! I should mention I'm running my code within SublimeText. It's seems to be my problem. Any solution ?

don't encode manually, print unicode strings instead.

#### For Unix

Set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` if the output is redirected or if locale (LANGUAGE, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, LANG) is not configured (it defaults to C (ascii)).

#### For Windows

If the content can be represented using the console codepage then set `PYTHONIOENCODING=your_console_cp` envvar e.g., `PYTHONIOENCODING=cp1252` (set it to cp1252 only if it is indeed the encoding that your console uses, run `chcp` to check). Or use whatever encoding SublimeText can show correctly if it doesn't open a console window to run Python scripts.

Unless the output is redirected; you don't need to set `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar if you run your script from the command-line directly.

Otherwise (to support characters that can't be represented in the console encoding), install [`win_unicode_console` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) and either run your script using `python3 -mrun your_script.py` or put at the top of your script:

```
import win_unicode_console
win_unicode_console.enable()
```

It uses Win32 API such as `WriteConsoleW()` to print to the console. You still need to configure correct fonts to see arbitrary Unicode text in the console.

Comment: Thanks. PYTHONIOENCODING looks promising. I'll check that as soon as I get home. (PS : I'm on OSX so i guess win_unicode_console and chcp are not gonna work for me).

Comment: @Tibo: Some wires crossed somewhere in my brain. Why would I think that you need Windows solution while your output suggests OSX environment. Good news, it is simpler on OSX, just set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` if the output is redirected or if locale (LANGUAGE, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, LANG) is not configured (it defaults to C (ascii)).

Answer (score 2):

The response is an encoded byte string.  Just decode it:

```
>>> pagehtml = b'qualit\xe9'
>>> print(pagehtml)
b'qualit\xe9'
>>> print(pagehtml.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
qualité
```

Comment: @Tibo, it looks like your terminal isn't configured for a particular encoding and is defaulting to ASCII, which doesn't support the é character.  Have you tried another IDE besides SublimeText?  Python normally detects the encoding of the output window and encodes Unicode text correctly.  There should be a way to configure SublimeText to report its supported encoding, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, it's OK in IDLE (Python 3.4.2) and in OSX terminal (Python 2.5) but don't work in SublimeText(Python 3.4.2)... => That seems to be a problem with SublimeText console (output window) and not with my code. I'm gonna look at "PYTHONIOENCODING system variable" as suggested by J.F. Sebastian.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you do not actually have a problem, except for understanding bytes versus unicode.  Things are working as they should.  `pagehtml` is encoded bytes.  (I confirmed this with `req = 'http://python.org'` in your first line.)  When bytes are displayed, those which can be interpreted as printable ascii encodings are printed as such and other bytes are printed with hex escapes.  `b'\xe9'` is the hex escape encoding of the single-byte ISO-8859-1 encoding of `é` and `b'\xc3\xa9'` is the hex escape encoding of its double-byte utf-8 encoding.

```
>>> b = b"qualit\xe9"
>>> u = b.decode('ISO-8859-1')
>>> u
'qualité'
>>> b2 = u.encode()
>>> b2
b'qualit\xc3\xa9'
>>> len(b) == 7 and len(b2) == 8
True
>>> b[6]
233
>>> b2[6], b2[7]
(195, 169)
```

So `pageuni = pagehtml.decode('ISO-8859-1')` gives you the page as unicode.  This decoding does the replacing that you asked for.